# EXCEL how to use IF THEN on a column and return a sum based on the column if the condition is matched

Tags: excel

I have the following input in excel:

```
a   0.5
b   2
a   0.5
c   3
b   1
```

this is what I want as output

```
a   1
b   3
c   3
```

basically i want to group by the key (a,b or c) and return the sum of their values (for a is 0.5 + 0.5, for b is 1 + 2 and for c is 3)

thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With column **D** like

```
a
b
c
```

in **E1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A$5=D1)*(B$1:B$5))
```

and copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this formula in Cell C1 and Fill the formula down, it will add up the values, then Copy and paste the results from the formula as Values, delete column B then select all your data and remove duplicates and you will have your desired result:

```
=SUMIF(A:B,A1,B:B)
```

Or a VBA solution for this could be like below, this will add the formula and remove duplicates and leave you with your desired result:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
    ws.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-2]:C[-1],RC[-2],C[-1])"
    ws.Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & LastRow)
    ws.Columns("C:C").Copy
    ws.Columns("C:C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ws.Columns("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ws.Range("$A$1:$C$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```